# submit a form using POSTMAN

Tags: api, postman

I am trying to login a web page from POSTMAN. Basically, I have to submit a form. Form data posted below,

```
<form action="https://www.revcontent.com/login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="cmxform animated flipInY" id="altForm" role="form"><div style="display:none">
<input type="hidden" name="rv_tsvm" value="919fb358fe5028ed53d40fca59766df0">
</div>                
        <div class="sign-body">
            <input type="hidden" name="desk" value="false">
                        <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group input-group-lg  no-overflow ">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username or E-mail" name="name" id="name" value="">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group input-group-lg no-overflow ">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" value="">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                </div>
                            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block no-margin " type="submit" name="login" value="Sign In">
                                <p class="text-muted text-right forgot-link">Forgot your <a href="https://www.revcontent.com/login/forgot/username">username</a> or <a href="https://www.revcontent.com/login/forgot/password">password?</a></p>
                            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

So, I have three input fields,

```
name : "user_name"
password : "password_site"
login : "Sign In"
```

In the POSTMAN, I have selected the POST method and URL is `https://www.revcontent.com/login` and I have defined the key and value in the `body` . I can login to the site with the same username and password. But, in the POSTMAN it is not working.

[image]

The Error it is showing,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Error</title>
        <style type="text/css">

::selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
::moz-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
::webkit-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 40px;
    font: 13px/20px normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #4F5155;
}

a {
    color: #003399;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-weight: normal;
}

h1 {
    color: #444;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 14px 0;
    padding: 14px 15px 10px 15px;
}

code {
    font-family: Consolas, Monaco, Courier New, Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    color: #002166;
    display: block;
    margin: 14px 0 14px 0;
    padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
}

#container {
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #D0D0D0;
}

p {
    margin: 12px 15px 12px 15px;
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <h1>An Error Was Encountered</h1>
            <p>The action you have requested is not allowed.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exact problem do you face? "it's not working" isn't a good description. Also, post a screenshot of your postman's "Body" tab

Comment: I have updated the post, Please check. Thanks!

Comment: They have couple of hidden controls which should also be getting submitted "desk" and "rv_tsvm". Also, there could be cookies they might be expecting. Study the request which goes from browser thoroughly and replicate it in postman.

Comment: I have tried it. But same error

Comment: Did you try the cookies too? Also, rv_tsvm might be changing for every request (if it is like a CSRF token). If that's the case you will need to do a GET from postman, note down the value of rv_tsvm and use that in post (like how browser would do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is 500 Internal server error, that means its not even checking your login credentials and some part of the application is blocking you from going to that route. I also tried on postman and I was also getting the same error. The culprit is `cookies`. So, you also need to pass the cookies with it.

Here is my postman working link. (https://www.getpostman.com/collections/c8459b16c8fb6fbe01d6). You can import it directly in your postman. Make sure you are passing the correct cookies, dummy values won't work.